# How to change a dataset of images to train-images-idx3-ubyte format

Tags: image, format, theano, deep-learning

I have 10000 images. I want to convert them to a format like 'train-images-idx3-ubyte'. This format comes from [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). I want them to use the deep learning methods described [here](https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials)

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how these files are loaded [here](https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials/blob/master/load.py#L17).

The use of `numpy.fromfile` indicates that the data are simply saved as raw bytes of a specific dtype. You can achieve this using `numpy.tofile`.

However, make sure that this is really what you want to do. If you want to use certain networks on other images, these images will likely need to be of exactly the same size. It is worth digging further into the tutorials - after a while the transposition to other datasets will become easier.

Comment: Thank you. What would be the parameters of  `np.tofile`

Comment: The byte values of your images. If `images.shape == (10000, 28, 28)` and `images.dtype.name == 'uint8'`, then you can simply write `np.tofile(images.ravel())`, I think. Although, if you look closely at the code for loading, you may need to offset this by two bytes. HOWEVER: I still have a hunch all this may not be necessary for what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thank you again, Actually, what I want is to apply the 5_convolutional_net.py script to my own dataset. The dataset that I have, is an numpy array with 2 sizes, the first size is the images, and the second size is the labels.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tofile'